# SQL query from Android App to hosted web Server

Tags: php, android, mysql, sql, sql-server

I am trying to figure out why i am getting no returns from my query,

I am hosting an online SQL database using a bluehost.com server.

The SQL database is set up - and i am using the following php to try and que

```
    <?php

      mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","username","password");

      mysql_select_db("richkbiz_items");

      $q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE barcode = '".$_REQUEST['Barcode']."' ");

      while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))

              $output[]=$e;

           print(json_encode($output));

    mysql_close();
?>
```

it is currently returning no value for item, even though the item is in the database?

Any tips for accessing an online database, where php and sql server are in the same domain?

Comment: Did you check if is it sending the data from your code? If you are saying that it's returning data, probably you are doing something wrong when sending the data.

Answer (score 0):

how are you sending data from the application? have you tried to echo the output of the php page to the screen?

Comment: try browsing to the php page in a web browser to see the output.

Comment: Yeah it is working when i change it to a basic select * from items where barcode = "1234567", must be a problem with my reqest coding in the app. Many Thanks will see what i can sort!

Comment: you can also Log.d the response from the server in your app, that should help find out the issue. feel free to accept the answer if it helps.